# Visual Studio: Is there a way to skip execution of code between two breakpoints?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I know I can comment the code but would be even better if there is a shortcut to skip execution of code between two breakpoints.

Comment: Sure, you can... but depending on your implementation (and specific code) there could be multiple different ways to do this.  Do you have a specific issue?  Why would you have code you want to skip?  What purpose does that code serve if it's fine to skip altogether?

Answer (score 3):

VS has a feature 'set next statement' which moves the program counter to the to that location and continues execution from there (skipping anything in between). You can read more about it at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2017#BKMK_Set_the_next_statement_to_execute. The easiest way to use it is to either use the context menu item "Set Next Statement" (right click on where you want to set it) or hold down the ctrl key which changes the green "Run to click" editor glyphs into yellow "Set next statement" glyphs and just click on where you want to set it.

Set next statement is a great tool but it's really dangerous as a debugging tool. You're using the debugger to execute code in a way which would never happen normally. The results of which could cause crashes or other failures easily. It's real easy to do things like skipping over the initialization of a variable that's later used and will now cause an exception/crash.

It can be used in JS, .NET and native.